# how to target an element without class or id

Tags: html, css

how can i target the 5th td with nth of type ?
or any other way without using classes or id's

```
<body>
<h1>aaaa</h1> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td ></td>
    <td ></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ></td>
    <td ></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ></td>
    <td ></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `tr`s only have 3 `td`s each, though...?

Comment: By 5th `<td>`, do you mean the second `<td>` of the second row?

Comment: yes   the second <td>  of the second row

Comment: I think your question is being downvoted because you weren't clear on this: " the second <td> of the second row " -- modify your question to avoid the downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a selector;

```
 <body>
<h1>aaaa</h1> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The 5th element would be this, I'm assuming you want to target it in CSS?

```
body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10px; // For example
}
```

Comment: i dont have tbody in my html  and there is a way to use nth of type and not nth of child ?

Comment: tbody i dont have , body i have

Comment: Yes you do, https://codepen.io/mcourto/pen/VEbxqR

Comment: The THEAD and TFOOT section markers are optional, but one or more TBODY sections are always required. If present, each THEAD, TBODY and TFOOT element must contain one or more TR tag groupings. To allow for backward compatibility with the older Simple Table Model, if no TBODY structures exist in a table, the entire set of row groupings [TR] are assumed to be a single TBODY.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can't select an "nth" of all elements of a tag while ignoring their ancestor elements. You have to select the ancestors along the way.

If the fifth `td` is the second column of the second row, it's:

```
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<h1>aaaa</h1> 
<table>
<tr>
  <td data-index="1">first</td>
  <td data-index="2">second</td>
  <td data-index="3">third</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-index="4">fourth</td>
  <td data-index="5">fifth</td>
  <td data-index="6">sixth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-index="7">seventh</td>
  <td data-index="8">eighth</td>
  <td data-index="9">ninth</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(document.querySelector('td[data-index="5"').innerHTML);
  //fifth
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is using javascript where there is no javascript tag.